# Is there a number separator I can use in #define in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Can I add a separator character that is ignored by the compiler to something like the following:

```
#define LARGE_NUMBER 10000000000
```

to separate the zeroes for readability?

EDIT: forgot name declaration.

Comment: you could try putting a comment like this `// 10,000,000,000`

Comment: `#define 1e10`, maybe... it is easy to read instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your `#define` is missing its name. It should be something like:

```
#define SOME_NAME 10000000000
```

A `#define` is essentially just a "search and replace" bit of text. When you compile your code, any reference to `SOME_NAME` will be replaced with `10000000000`. So the value you enter must be valid in the context where it is used.

If you wrote the code:

```
long number = 10000000000;
```

Would you be able to use commas or other separator character there? No, you can't. Therefore, something like:

```
long number = SOME_NAME;
```

simply becomes:

```
long number = 10000000000;
```

Any attempt to put separators in `SOME_NAME` would fail because those separators wouldn't be valid in the context it is used.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, because a define block simply replaces the defined word with the corresponding value (you wouldn't write `long myLong = 10,000,000,000`). As @Oliver mentioned, I usually just put a quick comment behind the `#define` statement to specify the value and units.

As a side note, your `#define` statement isn't declaring a name for the value. You would want something like this.

```
#define TEN_BILLION 10000000000 // Ten billion
```

Then, you would use it like so.

```
- (void)someMethod {
    NSInteger myInteger = TEN_BILLION;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say this is a good idea, but you can use the concatenation token `##` like this:

```
#define TEN_MILLION 10 ## 000 ## 000

int myNumber = TEN_MILLION;
```